# Enable WOL for Intel I218-V Card (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, networking, wake-on-lan

I'm having troubles in enabling Wake On Lan on an Intel I218-V network adapter. It's integrated in an Asus Z97-A board.

The BIOS is properly set, since WOL works under Linux.

For Windows 10, it is my understanding that you have to enable it from Device Manager, as countless tutorials recommend.

But I cannot select the proper checkbox, since it's inactive:

[image]

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `Power on by PME` in BIOS setup / APM. Without it, the NIC signals WoL but the board ignores it.

Comment: That shouldn't affect the setting in Windows, though.

Comment: @jpaugh It's quite possible that the driver knows about the NIC's PME capabilties via ACPI and grays out what is disabled.

Comment: It was the first thing I did. But the checkbox was still grayed out.

Comment: @Zac67 but the I218-V is wol capable, and plenty of people use wol with Z97-A and the same NIC.

Comment: What driver version do you have? The latest driver from Asus seems to be 20.1.2019.0, from Intel 22.4.0.1. Windows Update?

Comment: Problem solved. Installed Intel drivers instead of default windows drivers. A lot more options popped up, among which was wake on lan. Thanks anyway.